# ModelNotFoundException: ModelZoo doesn't support specified engine: PyTorch

Tags: java, maven, opencv, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm try to run some ML on Java (17) using Yolov5, DJL with OpenCV.

I have built a model and exported to torchscript. When I run my code in IntelliJ all works fine, photos are processed and the object are recognized on them... great :)

But when I try to run this app outside IntelliJ i have problems.
Application is built using maven and maven-assembly-plugin with jar-with-dependencies.

I run it using command:

```
java "-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\OpenCV\build\java\x64" -jar app-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

in return I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" ai.djl.repository.zoo.ModelNotFoundException: ModelZoo doesn't support specified engine: PyTorch
        at ai.djl.repository.zoo.Criteria.loadModel(Criteria.java:121)
        at my.app.Yolov5.process(Yolov5.java:70)
        at my.app.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

In pom I have dependencies to (0.19.0 versions + 4.5.5-0 in opencv [same as installed in OS]):

- ai.djl:api
- ai.djl:model-zoo
- ai.djl.pytorch:pytorch-model-zoo
- ai.djl.pytorch:pytorch-engine
- ai.djl.pytorch:pytorch-native-auto
- org.openpnp:opencv

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the respective Pytorch dependency into your pom.xml according to https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/discussions/126#discussioncomment-319676

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.djl.pytorch</groupId>
        <artifactId>pytorch-model-zoo</artifactId>
        <version>${djl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```